# How to kill "fast fork()" process without reboot?

Tags: linux, fork

I've found a Torjan on Linux system, it uses a method called "fast fork", like the code below

```
while(1)
{
    count += 1;
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        printf("there is something wrong\n");
    }
    if (pid > 0) // father process
    {
        /* every 0x1000 times fork run the evil code once */
        if (count & 0xfff)
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        /* stop the program if the job isn't done in XXs */
        alarm(XX);
        // evil code
    }
}
```

It's really effective and you can't find it via `ps aux`, is there anyway to find the process and kill it without reboot?
P.S. The code runs as a normal user (not root) and I don't have root access either.

Comment: Better to `setrlimit` using the `RLIMIT_NPROC` resource to limit the number of process that the user may run simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the process name doesn't change after each fork, you can use a method called "fast kill", like this

```
$ while true; do killall -9 process_name; done
```

(but how to get the process name if the origin file has been removed? sorry I don't have enough reputation to add a comment)